Facing 500 Error in Laravel on Shared Hosting
I tried to deploy my Laravel app [PHP 8.3.12 — Laravel 11.36.1] to shared hosting, and I see a 500 Internal Server Error message on the website. The message is not coming from Laravel but from the browser:
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server administrator at your hosting provider to inform them of the time this error occurred and the actions you performed just before this error. More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

I moved all files in the public folder to the public_html directory.
First attempt: I moved the other files to a folder inside public_html.
Second attempt: I moved all other files (except the public folder) to a folder one level above public_html.
Third attempt: I moved everything to the public_html directory.
I modified the URLs in index.php: bootstrap/app.php, vendor/autoload.php, and storage/framework/maintenance.php to point to the location of these files each time I try, sometimes like:
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
// or
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
// or
require __DIR__.'/laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

depending on how I move the other Laravel files and folders, but nothing changed in all these attempts.
I modified the .env file to use the hosting database instead of my local database and changed other settings that usually get modified for deployment, such as the type of app from local to production and the localhost URL to my website URL. This is all standard stuff that can be found in tutorials - the stupid AI bots suggestions don't provide much help.
I didn't change anything else. I used my project that I was working on for a while locally, but when it didn't work, I just used a fresh Laravel app without any modifications. I installed Laravel Breeze and deployed it to that shared hosting instead of my project, but I encountered the same problem: a 500 Internal Server Error.
What could the problem be? Any suggestions, ideas, or anything would be appreciated.
Note: The hosting provider has a one-click install feature, which I used to install Laravel on the website. It works, but when I go to the public_html directory, I see an index.php file that doesn't contain any PHP code—just a simple HTML file with some styles, an H1 tag, and a paragraph. There is also a "laravel11" folder inside it, which contains all the Laravel files and folders, including the public folder and everything else. But I've never known this structure - what I know for deploying Laravel is to set the public content in public_html and other files to a separate folder one step above the index.php file for security and all that stuff.
In the .env file, I found settings like APP_ENV=local and all the default settings that come with a fresh Laravel installation. One thing I tried was to copy my entire project into the "laravel11" folder to replace those default files with mine. After doing this, the website worked, and I could see the login page, but there was no styling on the page.
When I logged in, I received an error stating that the view was not defined, even though the views folder is in the correct location with all the files present. Everything is there, just as it is in my local environment. I removed everything and started again with the previous method, but there was still no result.
Here's my file structure:
public_html/
├── index.php
├── .htaccess
└── laravel11/
    ├── app/
    ├── bootstrap/
    ├── config/
    ├── public/
    └── ...

My .htaccess files:
public_html/.htaccess:
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Root .htaccess:
#=php83
AddHandler x-httpd-php83 .php
#-PHPVersion

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

index.php:
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

// Update these paths to point to the correct location
if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

// Update the autoloader path
require __DIR__.'vendor/autoload.php';

// Update the bootstrap path
(require_once __DIR__.'bootstrap/app.php')
    ->handleRequest(Request::capture());


Please edit the question to show relevant logs, errors, code - don’t describe them :).

@AD7six  what do u think I need to add ?

Please don't use irrelevant tags - or explain how this problem is directly related to cPanel or any shared hosting

A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message. Normally for Laravel, I'd also say check in storage/logs, but this particular error message sounds like the default webserver error, not the Laravel error.

yes 500 from browser this is is the last eror in error/logs [error] [client 102.97.34.47:0] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Try adding the LogLevel debug in your Apache config, if you can, to find out what might be causing the infinite loop
